# C scanf - unknown array size

Tags: c, scanf

I want to read values (float) into an array but I don't know number of values.

My input is this

```
Enter values: 1.24 4.25 1.87 3.45 .... etc
```

How can I load this input to an array? I know that input ends when enterring 0 or EOF.

```
while(0 or EOF){
   scanf("%f", &variable[i])
   i++;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What part of the pseudo code posted is not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can dynamically allocate the array and then reallocate the memory for it when the previously allocated buffer is full. Note that the conversion specifier `%f` in the format string of `scanf` reads and discards the leading whitespace characters. From the man page of `scanf` -

> `scanf` returns the number of items successfully matched and assigned
>   which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an 
>   early matching failure. **The  value EOF is returned if the end of input
>   is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching
>   failure occurs.**

This means that `scanf` will return `EOF` only when it encounters `EOF` as the first input when it is called because `EOF` must be preceded with a newline `'\n'` else it won't work (depending on the OS). Here's a small program to demonstrate how you can do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    size_t len = 4;
    float *buf = malloc(len * sizeof *buf);

    if(buf == NULL) {     // check for NULL        
        printf("Not enough memory to allocate.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    size_t i = 0;
    float *temp; // to save buf in case realloc fails

    // read until EOF or matching failure occurs
    // signal the end of input(EOF) by pressing Ctrl+D on *nix
    // and Ctrl+Z on Windows systems

    while(scanf("%f", buf+i) == 1) { 
        i++;
        if(i == len) {               // buf is full
            temp = buf;
            len *= 2;
            buf = realloc(buf, len * sizeof *buf);  // reallocate buf
            if(buf == NULL) {
                printf("Not enough memory to reallocate.\n");
                buf = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(i == 0) {
        printf("No input read\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // process buf

    for(size_t j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("%.2f ", buf[j]);
        // do stuff with buff[j]
    }

    free(buf);
    buf = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your actual concern is the unknown number of floats that user is going to input. You can use pointer to float, do malloc for some predefined size, if your limit has reached while taking an input then do a realloc to increase the memory. You need to take care of previously accepted data while doing a reaccloc.

Answer (score 0):

You need a dynamic allocation of your array since you don't know its size at compile time.

```
// INITIAL_SIZE can be the average expected size of your array
#define INITIAL_SIZE 4
// size will track the current maximum size of youe array.
size_t size = INITIAL_SIZE;
// dynamic allocation for variable
float* variable = malloc(sizeof(float)*size);
// check that the allocation happened correctly
assert(variable != NULL);
// i contains the current actual size of your array
int i = 0;
while (0 or EOF) {
   if (i >= size) {
       // if the array is getting bigger than its max size, resize it.
       size *= 2;
       // This will reallocate enough memory for variable.
       variable = realloc(variable, sizeof(float)*size);
       // check that the allocation happened correctly;
       assert(variable != NULL);
       // (NB: It IS important to affect variable to the result of
       // realloc, you can't simply realloc as in some cases the
       // original pointer will become invalid!)
   }
   scanf("%f", &variable[i])
   i++;
}
```

As an aside, please note that `variable` is not a wonderful variable name. Use a name describing what your variable is used for.

**EDIT**: corrected the size in realloc to alloc `size*2` **floats** and avoid it break horribly, as unwind pointed out.

Comment: -1, note that `size` shifts from being "number of floats" to being "number of bytes", which will break horribly. Also it's good practice to check if dynamic memory allocations fail. Further, it's a bit strange to mix real code with the obviously pseudo-code `while(0 or EOF)` line.

Comment: oops, corrected size to be "number of floats" everywhere. As for the mix with pseudo-code, I simply took OP's code as base to help them find where to insert it.

Comment: Would the downvoters mind to comment why they downvoted?

Answer (score -1):

```
i = 0;
while(scanf("%f", &variable[i])!=-1)
{   
   i++;
}
```

`scanf` returns `-1` when it tries to read after `EOF`.

Comment: -1, since it also returns 0 if it fails to do the single conversion. That would leave `variable[i]` with an undefined value, which is not a happy thing.

Comment: What do you mean by single conversion?

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions (the number of `%`-specifiers it processed), or `EOF`. So your code should expect it to return `1`, since there is a single conversion being attempted in each call. Also, `-1` is a very bad way to write `EOF`.

Comment: Ok got it. I knew that scanf returns the number of bytes read. Thanks for clearing that out.

Comment: No, not bytes. It returns the number of `%` conversions that succeeded. Please read [the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf).